# Chrome ADD-IN for take you back to a specific page after idle time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I made an ADD-IN for Chrome ( internal use for our infokiosks) who will take you to the specific page after an idle time. The problem is that it does't count any click, mouse movement and so on and take to that page no matter if you move the mouse, press a key, click the mouse. Pls help me to solve the problem.

The script is:

```
(function () { 
var minutes = true; 
var interval = minutes ? 60000 : 10000; 
var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 1; 
var idleCounter = 0;

document.onclick = document.onmousemove = document.onkeypress = function () 
{
    idleCounter = 0;
};

window.setInterval(function () {
if (idleCounter++ >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "https://myauchan.ro/store"});
});
}
}, interval);
}());
```

Comment: Why are you using an interval?

Comment: I personally would use a `setTimeout`, and then debounce on mouse/keyboard activity, which  then resets the timeout.

Comment: Thank you, @evolutionxbox, can you be more specific? I'm very new in javascript field, struggling  with a lot  of information. It is not very clear for me why the script passed over conditions and does't reset the counter on any kind of activity.

Comment: _"passed over conditions"_... it doesn't pass over any conditions. You're immediately incrementing the counter (`idleCounter++`) inside the interval condition. Since `(1 >= 1) === true`, the condition is met.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Thank youu for your patience - The problem is: ADD-IN is accepted and ran but the main problem is that after take you to the main page will take you again after 1 min no matter if you click, move or press. This is a reason of my concern and I'm blocked here. So, if you have any idea, or o simple solution , please help me to understand what's happens or why. Thank you in advance, Mircea.

Comment: My previous comment explains why this is happening.